# Specify which Junit test to run

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit

I am using Selenium Junit Maven and Jenkins, what is the best way to specify which tests to run?
I tried [Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) but found it too complicated.  Is there an easy way to specify which test methods/class to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I believe Categories is the way to go, you could alternatively [include/exclude](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) test classes in the surefire plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>Sample.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If you want to execute a [single test method](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html), you can specify the `test` property

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test
```

You could set the `test` property in your pom.xml as well and set it differently in different profiles, but in the end, categories is superior to that and a good test suite design practice.